# Python Nested List Creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

class player():
    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.deck = deck 
        self.hand = []
        self.results = []

    def draw(self,draws):
        for counter in range(0, draws, 1):
            card = random.randrange(0, len(self.deck), 1)
            self.hand.append(self.deck[card])
            del self.deck[card]

    def return_hand(self):
        for returncounter in range(0, len(self.hand), 1):
            self.deck.append(self.hand[returncounter]) 
        for returncounter in range(0, len(self.hand), 1):
            del self.hand[0]

    def simple_function(self):
        for counter in range(0, 3, 1):
            print("Loop", counter)
            self.draw(3)
            print("Hand", simple_cards.hand)
            self.results.extend(self.hand)
            print("Results before return", simple_cards.results)
            self.return_hand()
            print("Results after return", simple_cards.results)
            print("")

simple_cards = player(["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3"])

simple_cards.simple_function()
print("Results after function", simple_cards.results)
```

An Example result from this code would be

```
Loop 0
Hand ['B3', 'B2', 'C3']
Results before return ['B3', 'B2', 'C3']
Results after return ['B3', 'B2', 'C3']

Loop 1
Hand ['C2', 'B3', 'A1']
Results before return ['B3', 'B2', 'C3', 'C2', 'B3', 'A1']
Results after return ['B3', 'B2', 'C3', 'C2', 'B3', 'A1']

Loop 2
Hand ['C2', 'B2', 'C1']
Results before return ['B3', 'B2', 'C3', 'C2', 'B3', 'A1', 'C2', 'B2', 'C1']
Results after return ['B3', 'B2', 'C3', 'C2', 'B3', 'A1', 'C2', 'B2', 'C1']

Results after function ['B3', 'B2', 'C3', 'C2', 'B3', 'A1', 'C2', 'B2', 'C1']
```

How do I make the result 3 nested lists like [['B3', 'B2', 'C3'], ['C2', 'B3', 'A1'], ['C2', 'B2', 'C1']]

I feel like there is a pretty fundamental thing I'm not understanding here and that this question has certainly already been answered but I don't know how to frame the question better to find it by searching myself.

I tried append(self.hand) and extend([self.hand]) but both created more problems than they solved resulting in an example output of

```
Loop 0
Hand ['B3', 'A2', 'B2']
Results before return [['B3', 'A2', 'B2']]
Results after return [[]]

Loop 1
Hand ['B2', 'B3', 'C3']
Results before return [['B2', 'B3', 'C3'], ['B2', 'B3', 'C3']]
Results after return [[], []]

Loop 2
Hand ['C2', 'B3', 'A2']
Results before return [['C2', 'B3', 'A2'], ['C2', 'B3', 'A2'], ['C2', 'B3', 'A2']]
Results after return [[], [], []]

Results after function [[], [], []]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append` to add the **copy** of the `hand` to `results`. The problem with just appending the `hand` is that you're modifying it later with `del` which will be reflected to the printed results as your example shows.

If you change `self.results.extend(self.hand)` to `self.results.append(self.hand[:])` you get following output:

```
Loop 0
Hand ['A1', 'C2', 'B3']
Results before return [['A1', 'C2', 'B3']]
Results after return [['A1', 'C2', 'B3']]

Loop 1
Hand ['B1', 'B3', 'A1']
Results before return [['A1', 'C2', 'B3'], ['B1', 'B3', 'A1']]
Results after return [['A1', 'C2', 'B3'], ['B1', 'B3', 'A1']]

Loop 2
Hand ['C2', 'B1', 'C1']
Results before return [['A1', 'C2', 'B3'], ['B1', 'B3', 'A1'], ['C2', 'B1', 'C1']]
Results after return [['A1', 'C2', 'B3'], ['B1', 'B3', 'A1'], ['C2', 'B1', 'C1']]

Results after function [['A1', 'C2', 'B3'], ['B1', 'B3', 'A1'], ['C2', 'B1', 'C1']]
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly the sort of solution I was looking for :).

Is there any specific part of python documentation/tutorials I could look at that might help make it clear when I am making something point to another variable versus creating an entirely new value?

I think I learn through trial and error too much because I only partially understand the terminology used in python documentation so reading it doesn't make things as clear as it should.

Comment: @Diofsi You can check [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) for various terms used in documentation. You could try to read [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) from Python reference for explanation on immutable vs mutable objects. In short you can always refer the documentation when calling a method to see if it mutates the object or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep your code like what it is right now, and split only the results.

For example, i assume that your output is:

```
output = ['B3', 'B2', 'C3', 'C2', 'B3', 'A1', 'C2', 'B2', 'C1']
```

So, you can do something like this:

```
expected_output = [output[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(output), 3)]
print(expected_output)
```

Output:

```
[['B3', 'B2', 'C3'], ['C2', 'B3', 'A1'], ['C2', 'B2', 'C1']]
```

So, in order to edit your code, you have only to edit one line:

`self.results.extend(self.hand)` to `self.results.extend(self.hand[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(self.hand), 3))`

So your `simple_function()` will be:

```
def simple_function(self):
        for counter in range(0, 3, 1):
            print("Loop", counter)
            self.draw(3)
            print("Hand", simple_cards.hand)
            # The edited line
            self.results.extend(self.hand[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(self.hand), 3))
            print("Results before return", simple_cards.results)
            self.return_hand()
            print("Results after return", simple_cards.results)
            print("")
```

Output after the edit:

```
Loop 0
Hand ['B1', 'C1', 'C3']
Results before return [['B1', 'C1', 'C3']]
Results after return [['B1', 'C1', 'C3']]

Loop 1
Hand ['C1', 'C3', 'A3']
Results before return [['B1', 'C1', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C3', 'A3']]
Results after return [['B1', 'C1', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C3', 'A3']]

Loop 2
Hand ['C2', 'A3', 'B3']
Results before return [['B1', 'C1', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C3', 'A3'], ['C2', 'A3', 'B3']]
Results after return [['B1', 'C1', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C3', 'A3'], ['C2', 'A3', 'B3']]

Results after function [['B1', 'C1', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C3', 'A3'], ['C2', 'A3', 'B3']]
```

Comment: Thanks :). The line of code itself seems more complex than niemmis example but it allows more intricate slicing of the results which is useful if I don't want the entire self.hand

Comment: Yes, you can split your list within the steps you like. So you can undernstand it like this `[output[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(output), step)]` and this line mean: return a list of slices which are from output from the range i to step for every i in the range between 0 and length of output but with a step. For example `for k in range(0,7,3)` , k will be: 0,3 and 6.

Comment: Also, be sure that you can respond to any question within different manners. You have the choice to use any method you want that you can easly understand.